# What does [^*] mean?

Tags: regex

So `[^x]` means don't match "x", and `x*` means match "x" 0 or more times, but what does `[^*]` mean?

Comment: where are you seeing this used? I would think that the asterisk would lose its metacharacter meaning here, like `.` does, but if you could tell us which language, someone might have more info.

Comment: Also, `[^x]` does *not* mean "don't match `x`". It means "Do match a character, as long as it's not an `x`". There is an important difference between the two that often leads to confusion. For example, if you want to find words that contain a `q` not followed by a `u`, you can't use `q[^u]` because it would fail on a word like `Iraq`. You need lookahead assertions instead (`q(?!u)`).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It means "match a character that isn't a literal asterisk character."

The thing to keep in mind is that within a character class metacharacters don't need to be escaped, so `[^*]` is the same as `[^\*]`. Similarly, you could use `[.]` to refer to a literal dot rather than the metacharacter referring to any character. Outside of a character class you would need to escape it: `\.`.

Comment: Surely that should be `[^\*]` though?

Comment: The `*` character doesn't have its usual meaning between `[` and `]`.  (It wouldn't be useful in that context.)

Comment: @Nick - In character class, you don't have to say `\*`

Comment: This is not really correct. You should write "Match a character that is not a literal asterisk."

Comment: Tim's right.  "Don't match a literal asterisk character" could just as easily describe the negative lookahead, `(?!\*)`.

Answer (score 5):

It means a single occurence of a character that is not the actual character `*`. No escape character is necessary, because the asterisk has no special meaning inside a character class. This should not be very surprising, since the carat character, `^`, also has a completely different meaning inside a character class.

Answer (score 5):

`*` doesn't have special meaning inside a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), so it means literally "something that's not `*`". The only characters that have special meaning inside character classes are `-`, `^` and `]`. Other than that everything is taken literally. For example, `[^.]` means "something that's not `.`", just as `[^$]` means "something that's not `$`".

Comment: Actually `[[]` will match `[`

Comment: Also, `[a^]` will match `^` and `[a-]` will match `-`.

Comment: @manojlds, indeed they will, but I'm saying that they _do_ have special meaning, if used in a certain context. Any other character will not have special meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The search engine [symbolhound](http://www.symbolhound.com) is a good bet for symbol searches like this. Here are the [results](http://www.symbolhound.com/?q=%5B%5E%2a%5D) for [^*] :

[disclosure: on the SH team]